# General proof that the minimum value of $x+y$ from $\frac{4}{11} < \frac{x}{y} < \frac{3}{8}$ is $4+11+3+8=26$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, solution-verification

I found this problem and the solution on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/shafaambis/status/1336443272659492865) (translated).

> $x$ and $y$ is a (positive) integer that satisfies $\frac{4}{11} < \frac{x}{y} < \frac{3}{8}$. If $y$ is the smallest number, what is $x+y$?

The given solution is $\frac{x}{y} = \frac{4+3}{11+8} = \frac{7}{19}$. Therefore, $x+y=7+19=26$.

Is the solution correct? If it is, why is the solution correct? What is the proof that it is correct? And if possible, what is the general formula?

Generally, the solution will be, given $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{N}$ <strike>where $\frac{a}{b} < \frac {c}{d}$, $a$ and $b$ are coprimes, $c$ and $d$ are coprimes, and $a \neq b \neq c \neq d$,</strike> the minimum value of $x+y$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\frac{a}{b} < \frac{x}{y} < \frac{c}{d}$ is $a+b+c+d$.

Edit: it seems the bounds are also unclear. What are the correct bounds for the general statement?

What is the proof that it's right or wrong? Thank you.

Edit: If it's possible, please explain it with only 10th-grade math or lower.

Comment: Maybe $a,b,c,d$ needs to be more bounded. Let me edit the question.

Comment: @peterwhy How about now?

Comment: It will always be true that $\frac {a}{b} < \frac {a+c}{b+d}< \frac {c}{d}.$  And, it is frequently the case that $\frac {a+c}{b+d}$ is the number in between with the smallest denominator, but it is not always true.  However, I do not know the criteria when it is, or is not the case.

Comment: The second [mediant property listed on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_(mathematics)#Properties) may be related: "Assume that the pair of fractions a/c and b/d satisfies the determinant relation $bc-ad=1$. Then the mediant has the property that it is the simplest fraction in the interval (a/c, b/d), in the sense of being the fraction with the smallest denominator."

Comment: @peterwhy Okay, so what should be the correct bounds for the general case? Is it the $bc-ad=1$?

Comment: @peterwhy According to wiki $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are both positive integers so $c'\ge c+d$ and $a'\ge a+b$ therefore minimizing $y$ also minimizes $x+y$.

Comment: @peterwhy Oh, I think I misread the original question. I thought minimizing $y$ is the same as minimizing $x+y$. However, it's the same thing according to @NeatMath?

Comment: @Faris Only if $bc-ad=1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I were starting out from scratch here, I'd note that:

- $\frac{a}{b}<\frac{x}{y}$ means $bx-ay>0$. Since we are working with integers, $bx-ay\geq1$.
- $\frac{x}{y}<\frac{c}{d}$ means $-dx+cy>0$. Since we are working with integers, $-dx+cy\geq1$.

So we have the system
$$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
bx-ay&\geq1\\
-dx+cy&\geq1
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

So it is a linear programming question. It means
$$\begin{bmatrix}b&-a\\-d&c\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\in R$$
where $R$ is the closed infinite rectangular region that has $(1,1)$ as a lower left corner.

So applying the matrix inverse,$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\in \frac{1}{bc-ad}\begin{bmatrix}c&a\\d&b\end{bmatrix}R$$

Now $R=\{(u,v)|u,v\geq1\}$. So $$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\in \left\{\frac{1}{bc-ad}\begin{bmatrix}cu+av\\du+bv\end{bmatrix}\middle| u,v\geq1\right\}$$

Each of $a,b,c,d,u,v,bc-ad$ is positive. So the smallest that the second coordinate of the above could be is when $u$ and $v$ are at their smallest, $1$. So you will have the smallest possible value for $y$ when
$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{bc-ad}\begin{bmatrix}c+a\\d+b\end{bmatrix}$$

BUT we still require that $x$ and $y$ be integers. One way to guarantee this is to require that $bc-ad=1$. Then $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}c+a\\d+b\end{bmatrix}$. And the smallest $y$ is acieved when $y=d+b$ and $x=c+a$.

So it is sufficient for $bc-ad=1$ to make it such that the minimal solution to the inequality $\frac{a}{b}<\frac{x}{y}<\frac{c}{d}$ is $y=d+b$, $x=c+a$.

For example, with $\frac{4}{11}<\frac{x}{y}<\frac{3}{8}$, the minimal solution is $y=19$, $x=7$.

---

Furthermore if $bc-ad\neq1$ but it happens to divide each of $d+b$ and $c+a$, that would make the minimal solution be $y=\frac{d+b}{bc-ad}$, $x=\frac{c+a}{bc-ad}$.

For example, with $\frac{3}{7}<\frac{x}{y}<\frac{5}{11}$, the minimal solution is $y=\frac{11+7}{2}=9$, $x=\frac{5+3}{2}=4$. (The fraction is $\frac{4}{9}$.)

---

If $bc-ad$ does not divide either $d+b$ or $c+a$, then $y=\frac{d+b}{bc-ad}$, $x=\frac{c+a}{bc-ad}$ give the minimal real solutions to the inequality, but at least one of them is not an integer. Instead, we would have to look for values of $(u,v)$ not both equal to $1$ such that $bc-ad$ divides both $du+bv$ and $cu+av$. And it's not immediately clear which values of $u$ and $v$ would lead to the minimal solution.

Comment: What would be the general case of this?

Comment: @Faris It's there now, I was writing it down.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't quite understand it (and therefore can't mark it as the solution). Is it possible to be explained with 10th-grade math or lower?

Comment: @Faris, you can plot the region $11x-4y \ge 1$. That's $y \le \frac{11}{4}x-\frac{1}{4}$. So that's the region below the line. Similarly you can plot the region $-8x+3y \ge 1$. That's the region $y \ge \frac{8}{3}x+\frac{1}{3}$. So that's the region above the line. Look at the intersection of the two regions. To minimize $x+y$ you need to find the point in the intersection region at the bottom left. That's just the intersection of the two lines at (7,19)

Comment: So here the intersection of those two lines happen to have integer coordinates... otherwise you'd need to find the nearest integer point at the bottom left within the region I think.

Comment: @Faris Sure, I understand. I rattled this off quickly, it's not written in the best way. I may return later tonight, or someone may do a better job of explaining it.

Comment: @Faris I tried to write it more cleanly. It does rely on linear algebra, and if that is not in the tool set of a "10th-grader" then this will still be hard to follow. If someone else would like to explain it without using linear algebra, they should go for it. I'm not going to try that because parts of it would be tedious to type up.

Comment: @alex.jordan Yes, I haven't learned linear algebra, but thanks anyway for explaining it.

Comment: If it helps, here's a plot of the intersection of the two regions. Notice they intersect in the bottom left at (7,19). https://www.desmos.com/calculator/umyf0ynlng